# Choosing x and y coordinates for a player in a javascript platform game

Tags: javascript, oop, object, math, game-development

So the game level array is this, where `"@"` is the player

```js
[".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", "."]
[".", ".", "#", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", "#", ".", "."]
[".", ".", "#", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", "=", ".", "#", ".", "."]
[".", ".", "#", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", "o", ".", "o", ".", ".", ".", ".", "#", ".", "."]
[".", ".", "#", ".", "@", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", "#", "#", "#", "#", "#", ".", ".", ".", "#", ".", "."]
[".", ".", "#", "#", "#", "#", "#", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", "#", ".", "."]
[".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", "#", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "#", ".", "."]
[".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", "#", "#", "#", "#", "#", "#", "#", "#", "#", "#", "#", "#", "#", "#", ".", "."]
[".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", "."]
```

```js
class Vec {
  constructor(x, y) {
    this.x = x
    this.y = y
  }

  plus(other) {
    return new Vec(this.x + other.x, this.y + other.y)
  }

  times(factor) {
    return new Vec(this.x * factor, this.y * factor)
  }
}
```

```js
class Player {
  constructor(pos, speed) {
    this.pos = pos;
    this.speed = speed;
  }

  get type() { return "player"; }

  static create(pos) {
    return new Player(pos.plus(new Vec(0, -0.5)),
                      new Vec(0, 0));
  }
}

Player.prototype.size = new Vec(0.8, 1.5);
```

I know this is a math question more than a js question, but could anyone tell me how the x and y coordinates chosen in here? I mean `(0, -0.5)`, `(0,0)` and `(0.8, 1.5)`

```js
  static create(pos) {
    return new Player(pos.plus(new Vec(0, -0.5)),
                      new Vec(0, 0));
  }
```

```js
Player.prototype.size = new Vec(0.8, 1.5);
```

The [Eloquent JavaScript](https://eloquentjavascript.net/16_game.html#p_pJwDuA/gUR) states that:

> Because a player is one-and-a-half squares high, its initial position is set to be half a square above the position where the @ character appeared. This way, its bottom aligns with the bottom of the square it appeared in.

Could someone clarify this doubt for me? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Whats happening is the player is 1.5 squares high. So if you want your player's feet to be at 8, then your player's head must be at 6.5(8 - 1.5). When you run `Player.create(pos) //Pos is a vector`, it returns a new Player object with the Player's feet at the original pos that was passed into `Player.create(pos)`.